# SQL LIKE operator with parameters and wildcards

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters, wildcard, sql-like

I have a query where I want to return all Clients that have a certain string in the name with wildcards on either side. So the input could be "Smith" and i want to return all things like "The John Smith Company" or "Smith and Bros". I want [Client] to be prompted so I set up the SQL like this:

```
PARAMETERS Client Text ( 255 );
SELECT *
WHERE (((tbl_IncomingChecks.Client) Like'%' + [Client] + '%') 
ORDER BY tbl_IncomingChecks.Client;
```

The query is not returning any results. Please help

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It is probably just too darn slow.  Does your SQL support `CONTAINS` use it if it does.

Comment: Concatenation syntax in Access is `&`, not `+`

Comment: @msmucker0527 It is generally best to use & as you say, but you can use + as long as you understand how + works with nulls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MS Access uses * as a wildcard not %, so your query will be trying to match literal '%' characters. Use * instead unless you are using ADO.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx

Comment: +1 The wildcard for Jet/ACE is a little complicated in that it is **nearly** always * when used within MS Access, but % when using Jet?ACE outside of MS Access.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like your problem is on the '+' operators shouldn't it read

```
WHERE ((tbl_IncomingChecks.Client) Like Concat('%',[Client],'%'))
```

This got me in DB2

Comment: Yes but not DB2 or old school mysql imo

Comment: thanks. i'm new to this and picking it up as i go. CONCAT is an undefined function. I'm using access 2007

Answer (score 0):

How about using `REGEXP` function in MYSQL?

```
SELECT *
WHERE tbl_IncomingChecks.Client REGEXP concat('%', @Client, '%') 
ORDER BY tbl_IncomingChecks.Client;
```

Or just simply use @client as the `REGEXP`to find all clients that contains this client name:

```
SELECT *
WHERE tbl_IncomingChecks.Client REGEXP @Client
ORDER BY tbl_IncomingChecks.Client;
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69b18/4).

---

### As per OP's update on RDBMS as MS ACCESS

If you have a more sophisticated pattern you could use `Regexp` object within a MS Access UDF. However in current scenario you are better off with `LIKE Concat('*',@client,'*')`

```
'-- you may even send the pattern as a parameter 
'-- you may also send all the clients into the UDF itself for matching
'-- returning a set of matched names string

Function regexpFunc(ByRef strInput As String, ByRef clientName as String) As Boolean
   Dim myRegex As New RegExp
   Dim matchSet As MatchCollection  

   With myRegex  
     .MultiLine = False  
     .Global = True  
     .IgnoreCase = False  
   End With  

   myRegex.Pattern = clientName

   If myRegex.Test(strInput) Then  
     'matching values can be collected here
     '-- Set matchSet = myRegex.Execute(strInput)
     RegexFunc = True
   Else
     RegexFunc = False           
   End If  
End Function
```

**Here is how you may use the above function in the query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE RegexpFunc(tbl_IncomingChecks.Client, "Smith") 
ORDER BY tbl_IncomingChecks.Client;
```

Comment: @user1940127 please take a look at the SQLFIDDLE reference. 'REGEXP' is usually a better catch :) if you are using `MYSQL, ORACLE`

Comment: Well there's no 'REGEXP' built in function in MS ACCESS. I just noticed your update on the RDBMS. However there's 'Regex' object :) If you have a bigger more sohpisticated pattern to match, then I suggest you use a `MS Access UDF`. Otherwise, you may just replace `REGEXP` with `LIKE` to fit into MS ACCESS.

Comment: I can't get the `LIKE` function to pull anything. How should the code read?

Comment: @user1940127 In MS ACCESS you should use `*` instead of `%`, that's the only change that you need to do for your own query. I have provided you with an alternative if one of these days you happend to require these ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using from in your statement

```
PARAMETERS Client Text ( 255 );
SELECT * from table
```

Comment: i left out all of the select statement on purpose.