# MS Access 2007 - Receiving Syntax Error in query expression

Tags: ms-access, syntax, syntax-error, ms-access-2007, query-expressions

MS Access 2007 - Receiving Syntax Error in query expression. Want to delete a record from one table (Parties) using another table's (Export_Extras) field (EmailEfile does not contain Email)

```
delete from Parties where Document_ID in
(select Document_ID from export_extras where EmailEfile is not like '%Email%')
```

Answer (score 3):

I am almost positive the wild card is * not % as you can see here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like2007.php

Comment: I still consider myself a bit of a newbie, hard to give answers with conviction :-)

Comment: Hi @Newd you are right to be cautious, the wild card in MS Access is sometimes %, but you got it in this case +1. BTW the article you linked is limited in perspective.

Comment: @Fionnuala Funny enough I had actually came across your comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105280/sql-like-operator-with-parameters-and-wildcards and based my answer off of how you said outside of access it can be % but since they hadn't tagged anything outside of Access I figured they were doing it inside of access.

Comment: @Newd It is possible to run Access in ANSI 92 mode, which makes % the wildcard. There may be problems with ANSI 92. It is also possile to use the ALIKE keyword, which also allows % in MS Access. It is all quite complicated :)

Comment: Thanks All. Along with the incorrect wildcard, I had to change "is not like" to just "not like" Both these changes allowed the syntax to run successfully.